# running a batch file in a remote machine as an administrator

Tags: psexec

I am having a virtual machine which i am using it as a server. I have my local machine as a client.

I have a windows batch file in the virtual machine, a.k.a the server which has a series of command.

I try to run the batch file from the client through psexec. I can access the file and execute the file. But not all the commands are executed. They need administrative privileges.

The command that i use is

psexec \virtualmachinename -s -u domainname\username -p PASSWORD c:\foldername\batchfile.bat

NOTE 1: I cannot select the option of "Run as Administrator" in the properties of the batch file. The check box is grayed, that means i cannot select/deselect anything.

NOTE 2: I have given the user of my virtual machine full administrative privileges.

Any insight or possible solutions will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

If the account you are logging into with is an Administrator then your code should be working.

However the first thing I would try would be to add runas /user:administrator ie:

```
psexec \\virtualmachinename -u domainname\username -p PASSWORD cmd && runas /user:administrator && c:\foldername\batchfile.bat
```

Comment: There should be another `\\` before the host according to the PSExec docs.

Comment: @DavidScherer Yes you are correct. I just fixed my type.

Comment: @RandyRakestraw A great irony is misspelling the word "typo" :)